# Sending a PriorityQueue over Socket in Java sends an empty queue

Tags: java, sockets

I have two programs - Server and a Client. Basically the job of the server is to maintain an ArrayList of objects of some class 'Item'. Items can be added to the ArrayList or existing items can be altered on the Client app's request. Occasionally the Client App has to receive some of the Items that are contained in the list and that is where the problem comes from. The Item Class has a PriorityQueue of other objects (that are serializable) as an instance variable. The problem is that when the server sends some items the client receives everything but the priority queue for each item is empty (all the other instance variables of the Item objects are received correctly).

Now the code:
This is the part of the Item Class that is connected to the problem:

```
public class Item implements Serializable   
{  
    ...Some instance variables...   
    PriorityQueue<Bid> pq;

    public Item(...)  
    {      
        pq = new ProrityQueue<Bid>(); 
    }  

    public void addStuff(Stuff bid)  
    {  
        this.pq.add(bid);  
    }  

    ...other methods...      
}
```

To send the ArrayList that the client requested I just to this on the server side

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream);
oos.writeObject(someArrayList<Item>);
```

and on the client side

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream);  
ArrayList<Item> tempList = (ArrayList<Item>) ois.readObject();
```

I find it really strange that the client receives every single object it has to receive and all of its instance variables including the PriorityQueue but the PriorityQueue is empty. Why are the Objects in the PriorityQueue the only thing that is not received by the Client? Is there something extra I should know about sending a List of objects that have some collection of other objects within them over a socket?

**EDIT**: I am posting part of the code for further details. In fact for the communication between the server and the client I use ClientCommunications Class and ServerCommunication Class that handle everything so that the two apps don't have to deal with the sockets.

To send some of the items that are requested by the client I have

```
ArrayList<Item> list = handleItemsRequest(rim); 
//this uses the server output stream to transfer an object to the client's output stream   
comms.sendItems(list);
```

Code for the sendItems(list) method:

```
public void sendItems(ArrayList<Item> items)
{
    try
    {
        //oos is the output stream of the server socket
        oos.writeObject(items);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

where handleItemsRequest() is a method that takes some constraints and then return only the items that match them:

```
public ArrayList<Item> handleItemsRequest(RequestItemsMessage rim)  
{  
    //it is the new array list that consist of items matching the conditions
    ArrayList<Item> it = new ArrayList<Item>();     
    //items is the arrayList maintained by the server  
    for (Item item : items)  
    {  
       if (item.matchesConditions)  
       {  
           it.add(item);
       }
    }

    //it contains all the right items and the priorityQueue for each item has everything that it has to have  
    return it;  
}
```

Then the client app receives the list by calling

```
//this comms variable is different from the one in the server and is a par of a different class  
ArrayList<Item> list = comms.receiveItems();
```

Code for the receiveItems():

```
public ArrayList<Item> receiveItems()
{
    try
    {
        ArrayList<Item> list = (ArrayList<Item>) ois.readObject();
        return list;
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now the client has all the items that had to be sent but their priority queues are empty.
There is much more code but it is not relevant to this problem and I needn't post it all.

**SOLUTION** It turns out that before sending the list the OutputStream of the server has to be reset. Otherwise the client would keep getting the old instance again and again. Big thanks to EJP for pointing out the problem!

Comment: Hi, what is the Stuff object? Does it also implement Serializable?

Comment: Stuff is just a wrapper class that I use to store a String and a Float object. And yes it also implements Serializable so I don't think my problem is caused by this Class.

Comment: Do you have a custom `readObject()` or `writeObject()` method?

Comment: No, I am using the default ones.

Comment: Well at this stage I have to start questioning your observations. Are you sure the objects had non-empty PQs when serialized?

Comment: Yes that is what I first tested. Before sending the ArrayList through the socket I would use a foreach to go over every element in the list and check what is the size of each one's queue. That showed what I was expecting so I tried the same for loop after reading the List on the client's side and that is where it says that for every Item the queue is empty. I just cannot imagine that the objects in the queue can get lost somewhere when they are being sent.

Comment: Can you show all that code? Edit it into your question.

Comment: I have created a sample based on the above and it works. Sorry I cannot help but I would need more information on all classes.

Comment: Kevin, I have posted some more from the code but the whole thing is much too big and it would take too much time to explain everything. I will look for the error in other places. Thank you for wanting to help!

Comment: Post the code that calls readObject() and writeObject(), and that traces the size of the PQ at the time. I don't understand why you've posted what you've posted. It doesn't seem even slightly relevant.

Comment: @EJP code for reading and sending the list has been posted.

Comment: OK. Now. Have you ever previously sent the same object in a state when the PQ was empty? If so, you have to call ObjectOutputStream.reset() before you send it again in a different state. Otherwise you get the old instance again when you read.

Comment: @EJP that worked just as I wanted it to work. I was completely unaware of the reset function of the output stream and I should have posted that code from the beginning. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Do you ever close the stream? Try calling `oos.close()` after `oos.writeObject()`.

Comment: I don't close the stream after that operation because I need it throughout the execution of the client app. Closing the stream will also close the socket and I don't want that after that operation.

Comment: @PetarMI Ok, maybe calling `flush()` will help then?

Comment: @petter If the stream wasn't being closed or flushed he wouldn't be reading an object at all, let alone an object with the wrong values. He would be either blocking or getting an IOException, probably an EOFException.

Comment: @EJP You're right! I was reading the question sloppily. WIll do better next time :)

Comment: Just tried it but the client still receives all the items and an empty queue. Very strange how before writing the list of items every item has a full queue but the client receives an empty one. Only problem I could think of is if the objects in the queue were not Serializable but they are.